# How to download content of ?wsdl from endpoint address in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have an endpoint http address, let's say "http://app.ws/xyz?wsdl". I want to get the content of this wsdl as a `String` or `InputStream` or whatever in java code.

Wsdl may include imports of other xsd schemas and it would be great if i could download them too. If not I can always search for import links within the wsdl and download them with same method as first wsdl.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a library which does similar thing that SoapUI does when it imports wsdls?

I read something about `HttpClient` in `org.apache` but don't quite get the concept and how it could be applied on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

what is the aim of you? Are you trying to create proxy client? Why do you download wsdl source? Don't you try to download from internet browser?